# Iterate through child items in Excel OLAP filter with VBA

Tags: excel, olap-cube, vba

I have an excel OLAP pivot table which has a filter above.  The filter is hierarchical in that you can drill down and down several levels to see what you want to see.

I am trying to use VBA to filter to a specific level and then loop through all that level's child items to perform additional actions.  My problem is figuring out how to get to that list of child items.  I can filter to the level I need but that's where things get sticky.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
"[Accounts].[Business Bankers].[Cost Centre Code5]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
"[Accounts].[Business Bankers].[Cost Centre Code5].&[" & AreaArr(i, 2) & "]")

For Each pi2 In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
    "[Accounts].[Business Bankers].[Cost Centre Code6]").PivotItems
    MsgBox pi2.Caption
    MsgBox pi2.Value
    MsgBox Right(pi2.Caption, Len(pi2.Caption) - 11)
    Worksheets("Town").Copy ActiveSheet.Name = Right(pi2.Caption, Len(pi2.Caption) - 11)

Next
```

That for each loop doesn't work.  I am trying to figure out how to loop through all the child items that exist for Cost Centre Code5.

Thanks!

Comment: I would assign this `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
    "[Accounts].[Business Bankers].[Cost Centre Code6]")` to a `variant`, put a breakpoint just after than assignment and then use the watch window to explore the object and see what exactly is in the `PivotItems` member

Answer (score 0):

What I've found, in Excel 2010, is that when only one item is selected, `PivotTables("x").PivotFields("y").PivotItems.Count` is 0.  Therefore any looping is not executed.

This is the case even if your filter has `Select Multiple Items` checked.  In other words, you need to have `Select Multiple Items` *and* have more than one item selected so that you can loop over the collection.  Very annoying.

You can supposedly access your one selected item as follows `PivotTables("x").PivotFields("y").PivotItems` according to [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.pivotitems), but I've found that if I try to assign that method to a `PivotItem` variable I get a Type Mismatch.  Contrary to the documentation, the method returns a `PivotItems` type every time.  Unfortunately, it has a count of zero when there is only a single selected item, so you cannot inspect it.